# Send event from Java to RN

Tags: java, android, react-native

I want to send a message to my `React-Native` application when the application has `rebooted` or `crashed`. I have 1 script for each method. 1 script starts the application on `BOOT_COMPLETE` and the other script restarts the application if it has crashed. This works fine but i can not seem to get the events working.

**Error**

> Unable to start receiver com.my.package.BootReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext()' on a null object reference

**BootReceiver.java**

When running `adb logcat` the print appears in the logs after rebooting the application but the `reactInstanceManager` is either always null or crashes the application.

```java
package com.my.package;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager;

    // Constructor to set ReactInstanceManager
    public BootReceiver(ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
        this.reactInstanceManager = reactInstanceManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Log & Restart application
        System.out.println("  - REBOOT: Reboot script was called -  ");
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);

        // Emit to RN
        if (reactInstanceManager != null) {
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            params.putString("EVENT", "  - REBOOT: Reboot script was called -  ");

            reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext()
                    .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                    .emit("EVENT", params);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.tsx**

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("EVENT", () => {
      console.log("Device has been rebooted");
    });

    // Removes the listener once unmounted
    return () => {
      DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners();
    };
  });
```